# Number of ways of choosing identical balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we are given a bag of $n$ identical red balls, what is the number of ways of choosing $3$ red balls from the bag?
I know the answer is $$ \binom n3 $$ but isn't there just **one** way of choosing $3$ balls? They're all identical anyway, so it shouldn't matter! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is poorly worded. The number of ways of choosing a set of three balls from the bag is $\binom{n}3$; if the balls are truly identical, however, the number of distinguishable outcomes is, as you say, just $1$. If the former answer is intended, the inclusion of the words *identical red* is misleading at best. If the latter answer is intended, this should be clearer, for instance by adding the word *distinguishable*, as I did above.